# Angular stepper, show multiple components in one step

Tags: angular

How can I show multiple components in step1.

```
<mat-step>
<comp1></comp1>
<comp2></comp2>
<comp3></comp3>
</mat-step>
```

If I follow above code then, all of three components are rendering on one page, I need to show comp1 on page1, comp2 on page2 and comp3 on page3. After completing comp3 form, step1 will be completed. 
To do that, I followed below approach, On click next, I increment indexes for each step. But this is causing issue.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" labelPosition="bottom"  #stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
      <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel><strong>Your Info</strong></ng-template>

        <app-demographics *ngIf="index==0 && step==0"></app-demographics>
        <app-find-doctor *ngIf="index==1 && step==0"></app-find-doctor>
        <app-find-drug *ngIf="index==2 && step==0"></app-find-drug>

      </mat-step>

      <mat-step >
        <ng-template matStepLabel><strong>View Plans</strong></ng-template>
        <app-view-plans></app-view-plans>
      </mat-step>

    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

All the components have forms. Below is sample component

```
find-a-drug.html

<div class="provider-container">
        ------------------------
        <app-form-navigation nextPath="enrollments/steps/view-plans" [queryParams]='{index:0, step:1}' isQueryParamPreserve='true'></app-form-navigation>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the issue that you're having?

Comment: Step1 completed, user is on step2, if user clicks on step1 then comp3 form should render but because of ngIf conditions its not showing any thing. 

<app-find-drug *ngIf="index==2 && step==0"></app-find-drug>
This is not rendering. On clicking next, I increment index and passing that values to query params and from query params components are getting index and step values. Like for above component index =2 is coming from query param

Comment: I have never dealt with steppers before but I'm curious if your problem isn't because you have not set your steppers to anything but 0?

Comment: @JakeFromSF


No its not because of it. Let me explain you. 
<mat-step>.....</mat-step> this will complete one step.. 
So, in my case, step1 will complete after 3 pages. 
<mat-step> <comp1></comp1><comp2></comp2><comp3></comp3></mat-step>... If I follow this approach then all the three components are rendering on one page. So I give indexes and steps to make them conditional. Each component have next and previous button, on click of those buttons, I am passing values of indexes and steps